# Why would I get a NullPointerException on a Synchronized Lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have just a "Simple" Synchronized Lock Block as such:

```
private final Object screenLock = new Object();

public void Update(double deltaTime)
{
    synchronized (screenLock)
    {
        screenManager.Update(deltaTime);
    }
}

public void Draw()
{
    synchronized (screenLock)
    {
        screenManager.Draw();
    }
}
```

`deltaTime` isn't `null`, `screenManager` isn't `null`, so I'm a little lost.

I know that I shouldn't be putting a lock on such a High level, but the problem persists wherever I put the Block. I have two threads running to `Update` and `Draw` both with `screenLock`.

What would cause the `NullPointerException` on the lock?

Trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.dnx.manavo.ScreenManager.Update(ScreenManager.java:107) at
>   com.dnx.manavo.ApplicationActivity.Update(ApplicationActivity.java:98)
>   at com.dnx.manavo.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:43)

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the `NullPointerException`? Can you provide a full working example that demonstrates the NPE?

Comment: How do you know that `deltaTime` and `screenManager` aren't null?

Comment: @AdamBatkin `deltaTime` is a primitive, it cannot be `null`.

Comment: Could you please paste the stack trace, cause it seems to be ok , and you shouldnt be getting null pointers

Comment: Oh fair enough. Yeah, didn't read the sample code clearly. I mean, how do you know that `screenManager` isn't null? That would cause an NPE here

Comment: Yes, I know that deltaTime is a primitive. Was trying to weed out confusion. Thanks though haha

Comment: I debug at that point when I set it, and when I try to access it.

Comment: I'm probably barking up the wrong tree here (nothing new there ;)), but the `NullPointerException` is coming from within `ScreenManager.Update` not `ApplicationActivity.Update` method. From your code example, that would suggest that you got past the `synchronized` block into the `screenManager.Update` method??

Comment: @MadProgrammer -- Bad move!! One should never actually READ the exception traceback.  Much better to ask questions on SO.

Comment: @HotLicks or Debug there code... ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes yes :P - their* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Adam Batkin, and @MadProgrammer - I found my specific `NullPointerException` within some parts of the `screenManager`

I did some research and sometimes a `NullPointerException` will be thrown at the begining of the Synchronized Block, but in fact its being thrown within the Block.

**Other Reasons:**

- `screenLock` is null
- Code inside your Synchronized Block is throwing an Exception

Comment: Your research is moot.  In this case, the stacktrace clearly shows that the exception is being thrown in `ScreenManager.Update()` not `ApplicationActivity.Update()`.  It always pays to read the stacktrace *carefully* ... to avoid jumping to incorrect conclusions in your debugging.

Comment: It wasn't at `com.dnx.manavo.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:43)` it was within the `ScreenManager` `current screen`. I did look into both of these, but couldn't find the reason why it was being thrown at these spots because a thread was changing the values after it had instantiated the `current screen`. It was a weird case.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation of an NPE on `synchronized (screenLock)` is that `screenlock` is `null`.

Check that the source code you are looking at matches the code that you are actually running.

The other possibility is that the exception is thrown somewhere else.  The stacktrace should tell you where the exception was thrown (modulo silliness ...).

If this doesn't help, create an SSCE that demonstrates the problem and add it to the Question.

Comment: @dnxviral -- Short, self-contained example.